# How to go back to previous navigation state using swipe-left in scroll list view

Tags: react-native

I want to go back to `state 1(List View)` from `state 2(Scroll View)` through swipe left gesture.
I've implemented how to enter state 2 from state 1, but currently, the only way to go back is to click the back button on the navigation bar.

Any keyword/idea for me to search the resources?

## State 1

[image: inline]

## State 2

[image: inline]

## Action to enter state 2 from state 1

```
Actions.wordDetail({
    ...this.props,
    word: this.props.word.word,
    title: capitalizeFirstLetter(this.props.word.word),
    definition: this.props.definition,
    showDetail: true
});

const RouterComponent = () => {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Scene panHandlers={null} key="root">
                <Scene panHandlers={null} key="auth" hideNavBar={1}>
                    <Scene panHandlers={null} key="login" component={LoginForm}/>
                </Scene>
                <Scene panHandlers={null} key="main" hideNavBar={1}>
                    <Scene
                        panHandlers={null} key="wordList"
                        component={WordBank}
                        title="Words Bank"
                        initial
                    />
                </Scene>
                <Scene
                    panHandlers={null}
                    key="wordDetail"
                    component={ItemDetail}
                />
            </Scene>
        </Router>
    );
};
```